# How to save a cookie in selenium and only save the value?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to save cookies in selenium but anytime I try it saves the name, value, exp date, address, ... etc, but is there any way to save for just the value and nothing else? (Sorry if that's not a lot of information.)

Comment: write some code

Comment: you can modify the searched value to get only name

Comment: Please include a code snippet that shows what you are currently doing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.